# Get ids of filtered pages

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

i want to make API to return list of revisions which are both unflagged and marked with specified tags like it is done by [THIS](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specjalna:Ostatnie_zmiany?flaggedrevs=needreview&tagfilter=commons-filename-change&limit=500&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2) page. The colsest result i can get is [THIS](https://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&generator=oldreviewedpages&formatversion=2&rvprop=ids%7Croles%7Cflagged%7Cflags%7Cuser&rvtag=mw-removed-redirect&gorlimit=500), but it also returns lots of redundant data even if thre is no maches & list filters only last 500 unflagged revisions.

Comment: There is also an API endpoint for RecentChanges, but either way I couldn't find a an API parameter for filtering based on "Need Review" (which seems to come from the [FlaggedRev extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs).

Comment: @Noam There is oldreviewedpages but i cannot find way to conbine them in way I want.

Comment: Yeah saw that as well. Either the extension is underdocumented or it really does not provide a way for such filter via API, even though it does provide it via Special:RecentChanges.

Comment: @Noam thats right and this is source of my problem :/ I have idea, mayby to get list of pages listed by that page directly from it like generator querypage but i cant find this page as parameter

Comment: @xKRISTOFx [Quarry](https://quarry.wmcloud.org/) is a better tool as it allows you to access database tables for FlaggedRev extension and also [change tag](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Change_tag_table)

Comment: @arjunaraoc can you give me query formula, because I don't know databases yet.